# Can we access administrator settings of windows in a Metro-style application?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

Can we access administrator settings of windows in a Metro-style Windows 8 and Windows RT application?

I'm currently using c#. but answers for other compilers (for example, Qt) are welcome.

---

*administrator settings =  (Registry, `IO`, etc...)* -> everything that needs administrator access...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because a Metro App is sandboxed and only has access to the WinRT .NET Library and, if in desktop, 3rd party libraries.

This is because of security issues and such.

Comment: By native you mean "inbox" -- a C++ App is granted no extra permissions, compared to .net or JavaScript

Comment: Alright I removed that part, I guess all native can do is run faster.

Comment: So, we don't have tablet management or such apps in RT tablets? (But there may be some in Pro tablets/PCs?)